When should you use a transformer and when LSTM, GRU and other Neural Networks?
There is a lot of information on the Internet that the transformer is better than RNN in everything, but is it true?
Examples:
«What if I need to translate words?»
«Generate text, images?»
«Play a regular game?»
«Play a game that changes depending on the player's actions, that is, the neural network must have memory?»
«A game in which there are several neural networks that are forced to interact, develop and learn, that is, change topology and remember the past?»
«Explore the space around it using photos and/or distance and color sensors?»
It seems to me that the answer to the first two questions is a transformer, the third is a fully connected neural network, but the fourth, fifth and sixth?
So how do we understand and conduct a test to decide on the NN architecture?

This question might be a bit too broad. You're effectively asking many questions and ask us to answer all of them. I'd focus on one question at a time, so one specific question for each post. For example, "if I need to translate words, is there any evidence that the transformer performs better than RNNs?". Create a post for each question.

@nbro, I have just given an examples, I has not intended to ask for answer on them, it is my ideas, where it might be better
